# How to write own methods in class based views and call the methods in urls

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

Here is my code. I was just trying to implement this but could not.I am in a stage of  leaning Django

```
class BCD(View):
    def start(self):
        return HttpResponse("Huray Finally I called")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^login1/$',BCD.as_view(),)
```

And even i tried

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^login1/$',BCD.start.as_view(),)
```

It throws error.I have read the docs of django methods such as get and post ,head can be written they will be called directly according to the request made.But what I is need to make my own methods in class based views

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why can't you call your method in one of standard methods `get`, `post` etc?

Comment: If 5 methods are there to write in put or get appropriate methods.Then Even at the moment how to call the particular method for particular url is my point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call methods in `get()`, `post()` or whatever the HTTP request is. There isn't a start HTTP request so Django won't call that.

You can do the following in your view:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.start()
```

This return the result of `self.start()` whenever you visit your view with a HTTP GET request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am still not clear totally.So from urls should i pass the method name to get(method) as argument.If So can you please elobrate.Sorry for not understanding the things properly??

Comment: You'd have `BCD.as_view()` in your URLs, nothing else.

Comment: `GET` & `POST` are HTTP *methods*. We use `GET` to get data based *only* on urls (excluding cookies), but with `POST` we can *also* send data from client-side to server-side.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil actually, there are others, such as `PUT` and `HEAD` which are also supported by Django.

Comment: I kinda thought that, shouldn't have specified only 2. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Here I come again.Sorry to disturb again. If suppose I have 5 methods in one class based view.For one url request i want to call the particular class method.then should i write the differnt class based views or can i accomodate the logic by writing in the same class